# Clean way to write AND filters for List filtering in Java

Tags: java, caching, boolean-logic

There is a service that takes in four parameters that are used to filter data from a cache store and return the results as a list.

Assuming any and all of the parameters can be null or empty and it still needs to return the matching data based on the rest of the parameters (return unfiltered data if all are empty).

For now it is first checking with if...else statements on which parameters aren't empty and then using them with `and` filters on the list. This has led to eight if..else structure.

This is what is repeated 8 times with all possible combinations of parameters:

```java
Predicate<Response> predicate1= e -> StringUtils.isBlank(parameter1) ? false
                    : StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(e.getter(), parameter1);

if (!StringUtils.isBlank(parameter1) && !StringUtils.isBlank(parameter2)
                    && !StringUtils.isBlank(parameter3)) {
                return response.stream()
                        .filter((predicate1.or(predicate2)).and(predicate3).and(predicate4))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
            }
```

Is there a better way to perform this in Java 8 ? Repeating like this seems like an waste but am not sure if there are better functions in Java to perform this reliably.

PS: parameter1 can either be an ID or a position text. It is used for predicates 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, when a parameter is not there, the predicate is true.

So you would have :

```
Predicate<Response> predicate1= e -> StringUtils.isBlank(parameter1) ? true
                : StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(e.getter(), parameter1);
Predicate<Response> predicate2= e -> StringUtils.isBlank(parameter2) ? true
                    : StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(e.getter(), parameter2);
Predicate<Response> predicate3= e -> StringUtils.isBlank(parameter3) ? true
                    : StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(e.getter(), parameter3);
Predicate<Response> predicate4= e -> StringUtils.isBlank(parameter4) ? true
                    : StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(e.getter(), parameter4);
```

And then just a single filter with each of you predicates :

```
return response.stream()
                    .filter(predicate1.and(predicate2).and(predicate3).and(predicate4))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

About your parameter1 being used in two predicates, just put your predicate1.or(predicate2) as a single predicate, and keeps the logic above.

```
predicate12 = predicate1.or(predicate2);
return response.stream()
                    .filter(predicate12.and(predicate3).and(predicate4))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```